# Using a column entry as a "selector" for datasets in R

Tags: r

My array looks like this:

```
     Slide Index        A            B              C            DoseGroup
482    778     l        0            0              2       13Gy_p_75_42wk
483    778     r        0            0              2       13Gy_p_75_42wk
484    779     l        0            0              2       13Gy_p_75_42wk
485    779     r        0            0              2       13Gy_p_75_42wk
486   4700     l        2            2              2  14.25Gy_C_50pl_42wk
487   4700     r        0            0              1  14.25Gy_C_50pl_42wk 
488   4701     l        0            0              1  14.25Gy_C_50pl_42wk
```

I would like to use the `DoseGroup` column's entries to be able to select the respective entries in the other columns. I would like to be able to tell R, e.g., "Do a `wilcox.test` between the `13Gy_p_75_42wk` and the `14.25Gy_C_50pl_42wk` datasets using column `C`."

**How can I do this with R?** Is there some kind of way to select all columns having the entry `14.25Gy_C_50pl_42wk`?

Comment: Supposed your data.frame is called `x`, what about `x[ x$DoseGroup == "14.25Gy_C_50pl_42wk",  ]`? Or am I not understanding your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your data to add a third level in DoseGroup to make it more realistic.

```
txt <- "Slide Index        A            B              C            DoseGroup
  778     l        0            0              2       13Gy_p_75_42wk
  778     r        0            0              2       13Gy_p_75_42wk
  779     l        0            0              2       13Gy_p_75_42wk
  779     r        0            0              2       13Gy_p_75_42wk
 4700     l        2            2              2  14.25Gy_C_50pl_42wk
 4700     r        0            0              1  14.25Gy_C_50pl_42wk
 4701     l        0            0              1  14.25Gy_C_50pl_42wk
 4702     l        0            0              10  15Gy_C_50pl_42wk"

dat <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)

wilcox.test(C ~ DoseGroup, data = dat, 
      subset = DoseGroup %in% c("13Gy_p_75_42wk", "14.25Gy_C_50pl_42wk"))

##  Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

## data:  C by DoseGroup
## W = 10, p-value = 0.1175
## alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

To select data, you can use one of these two command.

```
dat[dat$DoseGroup == "14.25Gy_C_50pl_42wk", ]
subset(dat, DoseGroup == "14.25Gy_C_50pl_42wk")
```

Those commands are basics in `R` and if you read any introduction to `R`, you'll be able to do same.

So I urge you to do so, I you want to really enjoy `R`.